# Как программно получить 4 координаты краёв террейна?

Tags: c#, unity3d, terrain, vector3

У меня террейн разбит на плитки (0000,0001,0002,...,1103,1104,1105).

Как программно получить 4 координаты края террейна (Point 1 Vector3(...,...,...), Point 2 Vector3(...,...,...), Point 3 Vector3(...,...,...), Point 4 Vector3(...,...,...))?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Найти максимум и минимум используемых координат плиток?

Comment: @Геннадий П  да найти максимум и минимум координат плитки

Comment: Ну, пройдитесь по всем плиткам и найдите. =)

Comment: @Геннадий П Дэвид Блэйн как ты это делаешь?